# Input formatting for phone number via regex in element plus

Tags: regex, vue.js, mask

Some help would be appreciated with tiny but very frustrating problem. I'm working on Vue project with element plus library.
User input: '123456789'
I need to make it: '+998-(12) 345-67-89

Element plus have formatter, but I need to make it with Regex. Unfortunately I'm having a hard time making it work.
https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/input.html#formatter

I did only checked for number now and cant figure out furthermore

```
<script setup>
import { ref, unref } from 'vue'
import { ElInput } from 'element-plus'

const phoneNumber = ref('')
</script>
<template>
  <el-input v-model="phoneNumber" :formatter="(value) => value.replace(/\D/g, '')" />
</template>
```

Comment: Try `:formatter="(value) => value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2}).*/, '+998-($1)-$2-$3-$4')"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you very much. Seems to be working, but in my case I need numbers appear gradually as user types in. And again my big thanks to you, you made me make a big step towards solution

Comment: Hm, try ``value.replace(/^\+998|\D/g, '').replace(/^(\d{1,2})(\d{1,3})?(\d{1,2})?(\d{1,2})?.*/, (m, g1, g2, g3, g4) => `+998-(${g1})` + (g2 ? `-${g2}` : '') + (g3 ? `-${g3}` : '') + (g4 ? `-${g4}` : '')))``

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew omg sir thank you so much, I'm almost crying, damn. I was still stucked and searching for solution till this moment. I totally forgot that I left question here and your second answer really solved it for me. I don't know how can I express how happy I am. Thank you again <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```js
value.replace(/^\+998|\D/g, '').replace(/^(\d{1,2})(\d{1,3})?(\d{1,2})?(\d{1,2})?.*/, (m, g1, g2, g3, g4) => `+998-(${g1})` + (g2 ? `-${g2}` : '') + (g3 ? `-${g3}` : '') + (g4 ? `-${g4}` : '')))
```

The first `.replace(/^\+998|\D/g, '')` removes `+998` at the start of string (that was added by the successful consequent replacement) and any non-digit char, and `` replace(/^(\d{1,2})(\d{1,3})?(\d{1,2})?(\d{1,2})?.*/, (m, g1, g2, g3, g4) => `+998-(${g1})` + (g2 ? `-${g2}` : '') + (g3 ? `-${g3}` : '') + (g4 ? `-${g4}` : '')) `` re-formats the number by adding `-` only when necessart as you type.